# Dual-Boot Dual-Drive Launching Goes to Grub-Rescue

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

### The Problem

*Note: The Grub-Rescue Problem is at the bottom of the post.*

Hey everyone for the most part the title says it all. For quite some time I have worked with my desktop as a dual boot environment between Windows 10 for gaming + photography and Ubuntu for programming/focused work. Today I decided it would be nice to change my secondary OS from Ubuntu to Kubuntu to try and work with KDE as well as gain more experience with partitioning.

Through this process however, I have run into problems with GRUB's installation process on my system which I have described in the table below.

```
/dev/sda (My HDD)
|- /sda1 ntfs 100mb ~system_reserved
|- /sda2 ntfs 834gb ~windows_storage
|- /sda3 extended 96gb ~contains the partitions for kubuntu
|  |- /sda5 fat32 311mb 
|  |- /sda6 ext4 20gb ~new_root
|  |- /sda7 ext4 83gb ~new_home
|
|- /sda4 ntfs 450mb

/dev/sdb (My SSD)
|- /sdb1 ntfs 100mb ~system_reserved
|- /sda2 ntfs 118gb ~windows_startup
|- /sda4 ntfs 534mb
|- unallocated 355mb ~2_unallocated_partitions
```

So `/sda6` + `/sda7` both used to be the partitions that I would use for Ubuntu. However now whenever I try and install Kubuntu I continually get an error saying that :

1. `grub-install failed this is a fatal error.`

### What I have Tried So Far

So what I tried doing following advice from [this Reddit post discussing similar problems](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/z82f7/help_grubinstall_devsda_failed/). I was able to get some progress made, however, I continually arrived at a similar problem in that I would when running the `grub-update` command get an error about grub not being able to find the `canonical path to /cow`.

However, when I restarted my computer I was brought to the Grub Command-Line, *note not the grub UI I originally had when dual-booting ubuntu but a CLI*. From here when I then rebooted and loaded up the live CD again, I began running into the same errors again.

I would appreciate any help anyone can give and am more than able to post more information if it would help you guys understand how to fix the problem. I also am okay with deleting and reworking some of the partitions if that would help (not the Windows ones, however).

My *hunch* as to what may be causing this process to be so problematic could be the fact that my Windows 10 environment is set up to boot off of a different drive than where most of the data is stored. So since I am trying to install Kubuntu onto the HDD it is causing problems with trying to install grub there. Would it be possible to install Grub on the SSD (not sure if that would help, just trying to brainstorm)?

*Update:* This morning when I woke up I tried installing the bootloader options onto `/dev/sdb` but again I was greeted with the same error code (1) as above.

*Update 2:* I was able to finally get the Grub-Install to work, however now it is not letting me properly boot onto the Kubuntu install. I was able to get it to work by setting the bootloader partition to mount on that I chose to be the same drive which I was setting up the root directory of Kubuntu on.

Now when I launch any of the boot devices, I am brought to the GRUB rescue line. No longer able to access Windows either, I did not touch those partitions so I am not sure what is faulting the Windows Launch process.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I was able to fix the problems I had been having by launching into my live-drive again and using the boot repair tool. Just to note, I was given the opportunity to proceed because my computer had Flex-Net installed, and I decided not to continue at that point but boot-repair still had fixed the issue!

Now I am able to boot the computer properly, and load into the Grub menu which allows me to enter either Windows or Kubuntu!

> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FfmkB7pcD2/

This is the pastebin which lists some information from the boot-repair tool. I believe at least part of the issue I was having was from Windows-10 shutting down into hibernate as opposed to a full shut down.